# In rails, how to obtain the size and type of a file when using "file_field" to upload a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I using "file_field" to upload a file:

The file name can be obtained in the controller:

params[:upload]['datafile'].original_filename

but how can I obtain the size and type of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Use the content_type and size helper functions

```
params[:upload]['datafile'].content_type
```

Not sure why you'd want to do that in a controller, but any validation needs to be moved inside your model. Also try using a plugin like Paperclip or SWFUpload to handle uploads, for greater flexibility.

Try these links for a examples [Paperclip](http://jimneath.org/2008/04/17/paperclip-attaching-files-in-rails/), [Attachment_fu](http://wdvl.internet.com/Authoring/ror/upload/saurabh_bhatia11242009.html), [SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/)